# Multiple UICollectionView scrolling in same layout

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to build something close to this

[image]

As you see here , when you scroll down , all the view scroll

**This is my view :**

[image]

when i scroll down , only the second collection view which scroll

[image]

My view is like that :

[image]

I tried to use UIScrollView , but always the same result ? 
Any idea how to make this kind of layouts ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the first layout (red cells) with a tableView with cells that contain collectionViews (one horizontally scrolling collectionView per tableView cell). However, in your case, it looks like you want the top part to scroll horizontally, and have the whole thing to scroll vertically. I would do something like this: Have the whole thing in a collectionView with 2 types of cells. The first type would be most popular place cell that contains a horizontally scrolling collectionView. The second type of cell would be the individual hotel cells.

The layout on the storyboard would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W0He.png)